# ymaps is not defined

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

В head выше всех стоит:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1?apikey=мой_ключ" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Далее стандартные действия из примеров

```
<div id="map"> </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, что не так, уже не писал свой код, все взял из примеров

Comment: "Создавать карту следует после того, как веб-страница загрузится целиком и будет создан контейнер с id." var myMap; должен быть внутри function init() { }

Comment: @Anastasia Не помогло, та же ошибка. Весь скрипт находится внутри $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: @ttard Попробуйте вытащить ymaps.ready из функции ready jquery.

Comment: @ryzen ошибка пропала, но на сайте просто пустота вместо карты

Comment: var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {center: [55.76, 37.64],zoom: 7});   "map" - это div блок с картой

Comment: для блока нужна ширина и высота <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

Comment: @Anastasia   Ширина и высота есть. Получаю 403 ошибку от ключа апи. Никогда не было проблем подключением, а сейчас уже пару часов прошло

Comment: Тогда проверьте ключ

Comment: <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1?apikey=мой_ключ&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Anastasia теперь 400 ошибка. Погуглил - это за превышение трафика в 25к, на сайте, который от силы получается 2к просмотров в месяц. Мда

Comment: Про 403 пишите в саппорт, это не обязательно превышение лимитов, может быть и бан

Answer (score 2):

Решение всех проблем

```
 ymaps = window.ymaps;
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=<ваш API-ключ>&lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

Comment: Ключи как правило скрывают. Как полезен ваш ответ автору?